# Receiving multicast data on specific interface

Tags: python, sockets, multicast, packet, tcpdump

tcmpdump can view all the multicast traffic to specific group and port on eth2, but my Python program cannot. The Python program, running on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Multicast port is 52122
sock.bind(('', 52122))

# Interface eth2 IP is 1.2.3.4, multicast group is 6.7.8.9
mreq = socket.inet_aton('6.7.8.9')+socket.inet_aton('1.2.3.4')
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while True:
    print '\nwaiting to receive message'
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print data
```

When I use another program to send a multicast packet to eth2, it works and prints the packet. But it fails to see all the current multicast traffic. If I run tcpdump on eth2 on the same port and group as the above program:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth2 host 6.7.8.9 and port 52122
```

it sees both the packets I send from another program AND all the current multicast traffic. It's output looks likes this...

```
# Packet sent from my other program
09:52:51.952714 IP 1.2.3.4.57940 > 6.7.8.9.52122: UDP, length 19
# Packet send from the outside world
09:52:52.143339 IP 9.9.9.9.39295 > 6.7.8.9.52122: UDP, length 62
```

Why can't my program see the packets from the outside world? How can I modify it (or something else) to fix this?

Edit:

I should have mentioned, the interface this going over is not `eth2` but `eth2.200` a VLAN. (The local IP and the tcpdump commands are all run with `eth2.200`, I just changed that in this question to make it simpler.)  Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7901972/862710) that could be the problem?

Edit #2:

`netstat -ng` when the program is running shows `eth2.200` subscribed to 224.0.0.1 and 6.7.8.9`.

`tshark -i eth2.200 igmp` shows three repeated `1.2.3.4 -> 6.7.8.9 IGMP 46 V2 Membership Report / Join group 6.7.8.9` when the program first starts. When the program process is killed, it shows `1.2.3.4 -> 224.0.0.2 IGMP 46 V2 Leave group 6.7.8.9`. There is also an infrequent `1.2.3.1 -> 224.0.0.1    IGMP 60 V2 Membership Query, general`, where 1.2.3.1 is 1.2.3.4's gateway.

Not sure if it will help, but the routing table looks like:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         1.2.5.6         0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
1.2.3.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 eth2.200
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does `netstat -ng` say while you run your program?

Comment: Don't you need a `struct.pack("=4sl", ...)` on the `mreq`?  Ref:  [UdpCommunication](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication).

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: While running, under eth2, it lists: 
`eth2 1 23.13.16.41`, `eth2 2 6.7.8.9`, `eth2 1 224.0.0.1`. The 23.13.16.41 is another group I tried to subscribe to a while ago.

Comment: @Steve-o: I've used that as well, no difference.

Comment: I assume those multicast addresses are only for example purpose, right? They are not valid multicast addresses.

Comment: @Neal: Yes, they are examples. The real versions are all valid.

Comment: What else is listening on that group?

Comment: @Albeit When you start your python app, do you see the IGMP join messages going out over eth2?

Comment: @Neal and Nikolai, I restarted the server to stop anything else from running, and have posted cleaned answers to your question as edits in the original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally! Found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/163244/linux-kernel-not-passing-through-multicast-udp-packets) on ServerFault that addresses the same thing. Basically the kernel was not forwarding on / was filtering out the packets because it thought the sourced address was spoofed.

Changed the settings in /etc/sysctl.conf to match:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Rebooted and everything works.

Comment: Your answer saved me after 2 days of frustration! :)